# The distribution of *by*-phrases in complex nominals

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-number, nominalizations

I was recently reading *[page 39](https://archive.org/details/surfacestructure0000fien/page/38/)* of *Surface Structure* [1980] by Robert Fiengo when I stumbled upon the following dataset:

> (1a) The suggestion of a different tactic by John
>
> (1b) *The suggestion of depth by the painting
>
> (2a) The perfection of the mechanism by the scientist
>
> (2b) *The perfection of technique by John

It is claimed that (1b) and (2b) are out due to a semantic constraint which forces *by*-phrases contained in NPs to denote agents. Since a painting cannot literally suggest anything, it cannot occur as a *by*-phrase in (1b).

Be that as it may, I wonder whether the distribution of *by*-phrases here is more tuned to syntax rather than semantics. Couldn't it be that the bad examples are bad simply because the *by*-phrase and the *of*-phrase are subject to peculiar cooccurrence restrictions? If we substitute the bare singular NP complements in the *of*-phrases of (1b) and (2b) with more complex DPs, it appears that the examples improve somewhat:

> (1b') The suggestion of the lake's breathtaking depth by Turner's painting
>
> (2b') The perfection of many data mining techniques by Google's engineers

Is Fiengo's restriction really a restriction over the distribution of bare singular NPs?

Comment: I have no problems with (1b) or (2b). Compare "I was awakened by the telephone", "I was awakened by John", and "I was awakened by a loud clap of thunder". It seems to me that the telephone, John, and the thunderclap are the direct causes of my awakening, and similarly the painting is the direct cause of the suggestion of depth. To insist on a conscious agent with volition seems to me to be unhelpful. To me, in (2b) "perfection" and "perfecting" would be synonymous and (2b) refers to John's action of perfecting technique, probably by assiduous practice. John is the agent.

Comment: I'm pretty baffled by the suggestion that the by-phrase in (2a) indicates agency but the one in (2b) doesn't. If John is the person doing the perfecting, then he is the agent.

Comment: No. Look at the date on that article. Fiengo was merely espousing what he was taught at MIT at that time. It's gone rather out of fashion since then. It **is** true that the vast majority of _by_ objects, certainly in passives and also in other structures as here, **are** human agents. Mostly what people talk about is people, and that's the normal default assumption. But it's certainly not a syntactic constraint. I would say _the perfection of the mechanism by the scientist_ is just a nominalization of _the scientist perfected the mechanism_, and therefore follows the same rules.

Comment: I agree that padding softens incongruities. But I find 'the painting suggests depth' strange in the first place, so the passivised version won't sound much better. The argument that nothing other than a sentient agent can be used as a 'suggester' is nonsense, however. The 'makes it likely that' sense: 'The slight degree of decomposition suggests a recent death' ↔ 'A recent death is suggested by the slight degree of decomposition.' This broadening acceptable even 42 years ago.

Comment: The suggestion of depth *in the painting**. The door was held open **by the chair**.

Comment: @Lambie Excellent counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

There's certainly no constraint on *by* phrases in NPs that says they have to denote agents, that's just silly and the inadmissibility of the example given is readily disproven.

> The rhythm of the differences in height and the strong vertical
> accents, the contrast of light and shadow, the colouring and the solid
> composition of the figures, the geometrical pattern of the
> Gemeenlandshuis, **the suggestion of depth by the trees and the horse
> on the bridge**, all these elements make this composition a complex
> and intriguing painting. ([Sothebys](https://www.sothebys.com/en/auctions/ecatalogue/2010/19th-century-paintings-contemporary-art-am1094/lot.6.html))
>
> Two screens — one for each BOB — greet the viewer at the Serpentine
> Gallery (the main gallery space, behind them, is filled with the
> computers that run BOB) and show a pair of white spaces, each given
> **the suggestion of depth by a single steepled window high on the right-hand side of the frame**. ([The Spectator](https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/the-simulation-game))

The restriction-on-bare-singular-NPs theory is equally baseless, as a cursory search will show that bare singular NPs occur quite frequently in this position.

> The Japanese attack, which caught the United States by surprise, led
> to the death of 2,403 people and to a **declaration of war by the
> United States** against Japan. ([The National Interest](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/buzz/germany%E2%80%99s-declaration-war-america-changed-world-war-ii%E2%80%94and-world-history-196828))
>
> The purpose of this paper is to discuss **the absorption of light by
> non-metallic solids**, and in particular the mechanism by which the
> energy of the light absorbed is converted into heat. ([The Royal
> Society](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1938.0137))

A list of the top 100 hits in the iWeb Corpus, many of which also admit non-agents into their *by* phrase:

> 1       DECLARATION OF WAR BY 32
>
> 2       ASSUMPTION OF POWER BY    13
>
> 3       EXPLOITATION OF MAN BY    13
>
> 4       ADMINISTRATION OF JUSTICE BY  10
>
> 5       DECLARATION OF INDEPENDENCE BY    9
>
> 6       DESTRUCTION OF PROPERTY BY    8
>
> 7       USURPATION OF POWER BY    8
>
> 8       ABOLITION OF SLAVERY BY   7
>
> 9       ACCUMULATION OF WEALTH BY 7
>
> 10          APPROPRIATION OF MONEY BY 7

Comment: Is there a chance you'd be happy with, say, three examples instead of all 100? Just asking.

Comment: An agent is not always a person....

Comment: @Lambie Some contrast agents (sentient causers) with forces /  natural causes (mindlessly performing the action), eg _the tornado_ destroyed over 100 houses.

Answer (score 0):

I think Fiengo’s claim is unclear – perhaps more context would help - especially full sentences.

**By** can be agentive or instrumental: the distinction is not always clear.

**Agentively**, it appears in the passive of *John hit David -> David was hit by John*. This indicates that John was the instigator of the action of the verb.

**Instrumentally,** “by NP” is understood as “by the use of NP” and appears in *“The advantage is that the whole thing operates by gravity.”*

In the sentence *“David was hit by a brick”*. The brick did not instigate the action of the verb and (absent an agent) *“by a brick”* could be substituted by *“with a brick”* or *“by the use of a brick”.*

Consider *“David was hit with a brick by John”* = *“John hit David with a brick”*

More instrumentality is seen in “*I made it by hand*.”

I suspect that the essence of Fiengo’s claim is the **type** of adverbial that is created by “by+NP.”